# How to pass serialized array of form in jquery function?

Tags: jquery

In my project i am adding the form data using popup so i need to pass the data from one function to another function .and I want to passing the form serialized array with that function arguament to check wich value is updated. is there any way to pass form serialized array with function argument? thanks in advance.

```js
function show_edit_types(edit_url,list_url,id,old_form) {
  $("#add_item_form #item-add-btn").attr("onclick","update_item_common('"+edit_url+"','"+list_url+"',"+old_form+"");
}

function update_item_common(edit_url,list_url,old_form) {
    console.log(old_form);
    cur_form = $('#add_item_form').serializeArray();
    console.log(cur_form);
    var diff = _.isEqual(old_form, cur_form);
    console.log(diff);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li data-popup="tooltip" title="Edit"><a href="javascript:void(0) " onclick="show_edit_types('appliance_types/{{ $type->id }}/edit','appliance_types','{{ $type->id }}',$('#add_item_form').serializeArray())"><i class="icon-pencil7 text-info"></i></a></li>
```

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: _is there any way_....Yes absolutely! But what should we state about it as you have not given any code to look into.

Comment: I made changes in my question please find and reply @jai

Comment: Should i pass it by converting to string.